# How to remove � characters appearing in spanish language on html page

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, multilingual

I want to show multiple languages on my page, for Spanish I am getting question marks with black backgrounds.

```
Result on html page: 
contrase�

Original Spanish:
contraseña
```

charset is utf-8 and these Spanish words are stored in an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like an encoding issue. You will need to:

1. Store the data in UTF-8 (assuming this coming from a db, etc)
2. Encode the page in UTF-8
3. Ensure your server is sending the right header

You can find more information on [encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding) in this w3 article

Comment: i am getting correct data from db, but what i can do if my data is stored in array,

Comment: im not sure that an array makes a difference as its just a container for data - but maybe im missing something. could you describe your set up in a bit more detail

Answer (score 2):

[You could replace the special letters with these](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html)

So in html code it would look like this:

```
Contras&#241;a
```

and on html page:

Contrasña

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<head>
    <title>An XHTML 1.0 Strict standard template</title>
   // this is important to display specialcharacters
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" 
   content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the symptoms (“�” indicates byte-level data error: bytes that do not represent any character in the encoding being applied), it seems obvious that the data is not in fact UTF-8 encoded but probably ISO-8859-1 encoded. If this the case, [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) is needed.

Answer (score -1):

ASCII Codes are better in these cases ,Otherwise it will not properly display in all browsers

Comment: You really hate Spanish, don't you?